# How to fetch the element inside tinymce using jquery?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

How to fetch an element from getContent in tinymce using jquery

Comment: If you could post a demo of what the mark-up looks like I might be able to help out; though maybe those familiar with tinyMCE might already know enough to help.

Comment: I like to trigger event from image inside tinymce. I am using tinymce jquery version

Comment: But what does the mark-up look like (view source in the browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot fetch an element from ed.getContent() that easily. You would have to parse the javascript string in order to do so.

I assume you want to access the image tag you were reffering to in your other question.
This can be easily done onClick:

```
ed.onClick.add(function(ed, evt){

    // Firefox
    if (evt.explicitOriginalTarget){
      if (evt.explicitOriginalTarget.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'img'){
        console.log(evt.explicitOriginalTarget); // this is the img-element
      }
    }
    // IE
    else if (evt.target) {
      if (evt.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'img'){
        console.log(evt.target); // this is the img-element
      }
    }
}
```